# What causes these duplicate TCP ACKs be sent in linux kernel

Tags: linux, tcp

I captured these packets with tcpdump on Android device(linux 3.4.39),  these packets are in a HTTP GET Stream:

> 1  385.447794 Server -> Client: SEQ 12517, LEN 100
>   2  385.498345 Client -> Server: SEQ 3086, LEN 0, ACK 12617
>   3  385.497836 Server -> Client: SEQ 12617, LEN 1348
>   4  385.498644 Client -> Server: [DUP ACK] SEQ 3086, LEN 0, ACK 12617
>   5  385.498735 Server -> Client: SEQ 13965, LEN 619
>   6  385.498978 Client -> Server: [Dup ACK] SEQ 3086, LEN 0, ACK 12617
>   7  385.718843 Server -> Client: [Retrans] SEQ 13965, LEN 619
>   8  385.719280 Client -> Server: [DUP ACK] SEQ 3086, LEN 0, ACK 12617
>   9  385.733230 Server -> Client: [Retrans] SEQ 12617, LEN 1348
>   10 385.733602 Client -> Server: SEQ 3086, LEN 0, ACK 14584
>   11 385.909921 Server -> Client: [Retrans] SEQ 12617, LEN 1348
>   12 385.910449 Client -> Server: [DUP ACK][Window Upd.] SEQ 3086, LEN 0, ACK 14584
>   13 388.031541 Client -> Server: SEQ 832, LEN 0, ACK 4192, FIN
>   14 388.031681 Client -> Server: SEQ 3086, LEN 0, ACK 14584, FIN

Client is my device.

**What causes these duplicate TCP ACKs be sent by client?**

UPDATE:
**Why client send previous DUP ACK(#4) after receiving subsequent TCP packet(#3)?**

Thanks.

Comment: I want to know if Linux kernel reading packet and sending ACK be processing in defferent thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What causes these duplicate TCP ACKs be sent by client?**

The `receiver (client)` sends the `ACK#` as the `SEQ#` it expects next from the `sender (server)`.

In your example,  Server sent:

```
1 385.447794 Server -> Client: SEQ 12517, LEN 100
```

the `client` receives it and then asks for the packet with `SEQ#` `12517+100 = 12617` by placing `ACK = 12617`

```
2 385.498345 Client -> Server: SEQ 3086, LEN 0, ACK 12617
```

If the packet with `SEQ#` `12617`:

```
3 385.497836 Server -> Client: SEQ 12617, LEN 1348
```

is lost and is not received by the `receiver`, then the `receiver` will send a `duplicate ACK` which is an indication to the `sender` to re-transmit the packet (indicating the packet has been lost).

```
4 385.498644 Client -> Server: [DUP ACK] SEQ 3086, LEN 0, ACK 12617
```

> **Why client send previous DUP ACK(#4) after receiving subsequent TCP packet(#3)?**

Because the packets with `SEQ#12617` seem to be lost in the channel, the `client` is not receiving those packets. Hence, the duplicate `ACK 12617` to indicate the `server` to re-transmit it.

> **I want to know if Linux kernel reading packet and sending ACK be processing in different thread?**

It can not be different threads since the thread generates the `ACKS#` on the basis of the `SEQ#` it has received. So, it cannot be two different threads. And even if they were, one will have to wait for the information from the other (synchronized).

Comment: Thanks! these packets are captured on client, SEQ#12617 have been captured yet, would it possible be lost in kernel upper layer? is it a problem of kernel?

Comment: I am not an expert, but this is what happens theoretically. Chances of the packet getting lost in the kernel are very slim.

Comment: @brokenfoot Does this mean that if there are lots of [DUP ACKs] being sent, then there is some network issue on the client side (as lots of packets are getting lost in transit)?

Comment: The client is sending the DUP ACK after less than a millisecond. I don't think any timeout happened in that time.